# Avoiding null in variable assignment

Tags: ruby

I want to get empty string or the string value of the object

Which code you will use and why?

```
value = object.to_s
```

or this

```
value = object.nil? ? "" : object
```

Comment: The second alternative doesn't result in a string, so I guess there's a typo?

Comment: @TryPyPy if you are going to print `value` right after those statements, there is no difference. You just need something that `responds_to?` `to_s`

Comment: I want to express in my code that there is check for nil and the object could be actually nil, so that if someone is reading my code to be aware of that. so probably the value = object || "" will fits best my style even that object.to_s is shorter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `object` is either `nil` or a string, you can just do `value = object || ""`.

If it can be anything and you want to get a string, your second solution doesn't actually do what you want, since it won't turn the object into a string if it's not nil. To fix that your second solution would become `value = object.nil? ? object.to_s : ""`. Of course since now you're calling `to_s` in both solutions there is no reason to prefer the second over the first, so I'd go with the first.

Comment: if it's a string I would definitely go for the || solution

Comment: If object is always either nil or string, you do not need to do either of the above because nil.to_s returns "" . Thus all you need is object.to_s You second option (checking object.nil?) gains you absolutely nothing at all... however your first option (using object || "") will also work appropriately if object is *not* nil, but is false... and it's what I'd choose.... it's also shorter, which means it's easier to read. :)

Comment: @Taryn: "You second option (checking object.nil?) gains you absolutely nothing at all" That's what I said. Note that I recommend going with `object.to_s` in that case.

Answer (score 5):

I've read in [here(act_as_good_style)](http://rubyglasses.blogspot.com/2007/08/actsasgoodstyle.html) (search for `.nil?` first occurrence) that you should not check for `.nil?` unless you really want to check that, while if you want to know if the object is valued you should go for something like that

```
value = object ? object.to_s : ''
```

That by the way fits very well with my policy standard behavior first(exception for very short code first when else statement too long).

Comment: The thing I don't get is why you'd want to explicitly handle nil when just `value = object.to_s` will do the exact same thing anyway.

Comment: Also, this code won't work when `object === false`.

Comment: you're both right, thanks for correcting me... beh that link is not mine and written by somebody that knows what she says...

Answer (score 4):

I would do:

`v = object.to_s`

nil.to_s returns "".

Remember nil is also an object in ruby.

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case, using `object.to_s`, you don't actually need to check for `nil` at all since ruby handles this for you. If the object is `nil` it will return an empty string.

Evidence from the irb:

- `object = nil # => nil`
- `object.to_s #  => ""`
- `object = Object.new # => #<Object:0x10132e220>`
- `object.to_s # => "#<Object:0x10132e220>"`

Answer (score 2):

I would do this, personally:

```
value = object unless onject.nil?
```

This seems a little more expressive to me.  Its something I wish we could do in C++, instead of using the ternary operator.

Comment: hmm, you may need to spell-check and logic-check that example... :)